# How to test for an an empty Redis key in python

Tags: python, redis

I am using redis-py (https://redis-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

lets say I have some redis keys saved and av. 'av' has no assigned value so using the command line, I can do:

```
>>> redis.get('saved')
Out[4]: 'None'
>>> redis.get('av')
>>> redis.get('saved')
Out[6]: 'None'
```

How would you test for 'no assigned value' for a key in this context?

Comment: Is `if redis.get('av')`:` not working?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Does 'redis.get('av')' evaluate to False?

Comment: Check the command EXISTS in Redis.

Comment: @user61629 It looks like if it doesn't find the key it returns `None`, which would be in line with how `get()` works for `dict`s (this `get()` is probably inherited from `dict`). Run this and see what it says: `redis.get('av') is None`

Answer (score 36):

You should use the method [`exists`](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#redis.StrictRedis.exists), which returns a boolean - `True` if your key is set, `False` otherwise. You should avoid the use of `get` for that, as it can raise an exception if you have a list value for that key.

Example:

```
>>> redis.exists("av")
False
```

Comment: With redis v3.0, it no longer returns a boolean. It now returns the number of keys that were found in the db, as you can now pass multiple keys to `exists`. As `0` is falsey in python, most code should still work, but it is good to know about this change.

Comment: Exceptions are clearer, the fact that something raises an exception is not an issue and can in fact be desired.